# Debootstrap - issue trying to start the network

Tags: 11.10, server, networking, debootstrap

I've just installed ubuntu 11.10 under /var/chroot/oneiric following [this tutorial](http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/ChrootSetup#UbuntuOneiric).
All seems to work properly, but unfortunatly I can't get the network working...
I'd like to have a separate system to allow ssh login without access the real system...

I've the following /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.4
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
```

but when I reboot the physical server, and even when I run

```
sudo chroot /var/chroot/oneiric
```

It doesn't connect the network, I also ran `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` but all I got was being disconnected from the physical server (i'm using SSH). Then I needed to reboot the real server.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To access the internet through your chrooted environment, please, check the DNS configuration inside /etc/resolv.conf file of your chrooted environment. Copy it from your physical server if its empty.

Now, to accomplish what you want, which is prevent your ssh users to access the real system using a chrooted environment, you shouldnt follow this tutotial you posted. This is to create a isolated environment to build debian/ubuntu packages.

You may want to follow [this article](http://www.marthijnvandenheuvel.com/2010/03/10/how-to-create-a-chroot-ssh-user-in-ubuntu/).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

For my PXE servers I use a different /etc/network/interfaces configuration to use the existing IP from the PXE boot.

```
 iface eth0 inet manual
 pre-down false
```

If your problem is hostname resolution related, when using debootstrap it's necessary to manually configure your hosts file. I used an entry as follows:

```
 johnf@argon:~$ cat /etc/hosts
 127.0.0.1       localhost
 127.0.1.1       argon
```